# How to plot two functions together when one of them needs to be a series of dots, with common labels and colors?

Tags: plotting, functions, color, labeling, dot

I have two functions that I want to plot together. I want to plot the non-linear and the linear (NL and L in my code) functions together, but I wish that the NL function is plotted as a series of dots instead of a rigid line. While, each value of the VOLTAGES has a common label and color. The code I have is

```
T = 298.15(*K*);
k1 = 1.38064852*10^-23 (*J/K*);
\[Epsilon]0 = 8.85418781761*10^-12 (*C^2/N m^2||F/m||C/V m*);
\[Epsilon] = 78.5;
\[Epsilon]R = \[Epsilon] \[Epsilon]0 (*C^2/N m^2||F/m||C/Vm*);
z = 1;
e1 = 1.60217733*10^-19 (*C*);
NA = 6.022140857*10^23 (*mol^-1*);
a = 4.25(*\[Angstrom]*);
a1 = a*10^-10 (*m*);
x1 = x*10^-10 (*m*);
VOLTAGES = {10, 20, 50, 100, 300, 400} (*mV*);
L\[Sigma]MKS[\[Rho]0_, \[Psi]H_, x_] = 
  Piecewise[{{0, 
     0 <= x1 < a1/2}, {\[Epsilon]R Sqrt[(
      2 \[Rho]0 *(10^3) NA (e1^2) (
       z^2) )/(\[Epsilon]R k1 T)] \[Psi]H /
      1000 Exp[\[Kappa]MKS[\[Rho]0] (a1/2 - x1)], 
     x1 >= a1/2}}](*C/m^2*);
NL\[Sigma]MKS[\[Rho]0_, \[Psi]H_, x_] = 
  Piecewise[{{0, 
     0 <= x1 < a1/2}, {(
      4 \[Epsilon]R Sqrt[(
       2 \[Rho]0 *(10^3) NA (e1^2) (z^2) )/(\[Epsilon]R k1 T)] k1 T)/(
       z e1) (((Exp[(z e1 \[Psi]H/1000)/(k1 T)] - 1) Exp[
           Sqrt[(2 \[Rho]0 *(10^3) NA (e1^2) (
             z^2) )/(\[Epsilon]R k1 T)] (a1/2 - x1)])/((Exp[(
             z e1 \[Psi]H/1000)/(2 k1 T)] + 
            1)^2 - ((Exp[(z e1 \[Psi]H/1000)/(2 k1 T)] - 1) Exp[
             Sqrt[(2 \[Rho]0 *(10^3) NA (e1^2) (
               z^2) )/(\[Epsilon]R k1 T)] (a1/2 - x1)])^2)), 
     x1 >= a1/2}}](*C/m^2*);
```

Currently, I have this code in order to plot each function, however I do not know how to combine them and plot one of them as a series of dots.

```
Show[{Plot[
   Evaluate@
    Table[NL\[Sigma]MKS[0.001, \[Psi]H, a x], {\[Psi]H, 
      VOLTAGES}], {x, 0, 80}, PlotRange -> {-2.5 10^-4, 0.01}, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[{"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Psi]\), \(H\)]\)=10 [mV]", 
      "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Psi]\), \(H\)]\)=20 [mV]", 
      "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Psi]\), \(H\)]\)=50 [mV]", 
      "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Psi]\), \(H\)]\)=100 [mV]", 
      "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Psi]\), \(H\)]\)=300 [mV]", 
      "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Psi]\), \(H\)]\)=400 [mV]"}, {0.85, 
      0.5}]], Graphics[
   Text[Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Rho]\), \(0\)]\)= 0.001 M", 
     Black, Italic, 15], {40, 8.975 10^-3}]]}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x/a", 
   "\[Sigma](x)   [C/\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(m\), \(2\)]\)]"}, 
 ImageSize -> Large] 
Show[{Plot[
   Evaluate@
    Table[L\[Sigma]MKS[0.001, \[Psi]H, a x], {\[Psi]H, VOLTAGES}], {x,
     0, 80}, PlotRange -> {-2.5 10^-4, 0.01}, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[{"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Psi]\), \(H\)]\)=10 [mV]", 
      "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Psi]\), \(H\)]\)=20 [mV]", 
      "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Psi]\), \(H\)]\)=50 [mV]", 
      "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Psi]\), \(H\)]\)=100 [mV]", 
      "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Psi]\), \(H\)]\)=300 [mV]", 
      "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Psi]\), \(H\)]\)=400 [mV]"}, {0.85, 
      0.5}]], Graphics[
   Text[Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Rho]\), \(0\)]\)= 0.001 M", 
     Black, Italic, 15], {40, 8.975 10^-3}]]}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x/a", 
   "\[Sigma](x)   [C/\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(m\), \(2\)]\)]"}, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

Any ideas will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `\[Kappa]MKS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine plots using `Show`.

Since `\[Kappa]MKS` was not defined, I made a random guess for the definition, for demonstration purposes. I also made a few other adjustments because blue variables inside functions make me nervous.

```
T = 298.15(*K*);
k1 = 1.38064852*10^-23 (*J/K*);
\[Epsilon]0 = 8.85418781761*10^-12 (*C^2/N m^2||F/m||C/V m*);
\[Epsilon] = 78.5;
\[Epsilon]R = \[Epsilon] \[Epsilon]0 (*C^2/N m^2||F/m||C/Vm*);
z = 1;
e1 = 1.60217733*10^-19 (*C*);
NA = 6.022140857*10^23 (*mol^-1*);
a = 4.25(*\[Angstrom]*);
a1 = a*10^-10 (*m*);
VOLTAGES = {10, 20, 50, 100, 300, 400} (*mV*);

\[Kappa]MKS[\[Rho]0_] := 25 \[Rho]0; (* random guess for definition *)


L\[Sigma]MKS[\[Rho]0_, \[Psi]H_, x_] := 
 Piecewise[{{0, 0 <= x < a1/2}, {\[Epsilon]R Sqrt[(2 \[Rho]0*(10^3) NA (e1^2)(z^2))/(\
\[Epsilon]R k1 T)] \[Psi]H/1000 Exp[\[Kappa]MKS[\[Rho]0] (a1/2 - x)], x >= a1/2}}](*C/m^2*);

NL\[Sigma]MKS[\[Rho]0_, \[Psi]H_, x_] := 
  Piecewise[{{0, 0 <= x < a1/2}, {(4 \[Epsilon]R Sqrt[(2 \[Rho]0*(10^3) NA (e1^2) \
(z^2))/(\[Epsilon]R k1 T)] k1 T)/(z e1) (((Exp[(z e1 \[Psi]H/1000)/(k1 T)] - 1) Exp[Sqrt[(2 \[Rho]0*(10^3) NA (e1^2) (z^2))/(\[Epsilon]R k1 \
T)] (a1/2 - x)])/((Exp[(z e1 \[Psi]H/1000)/(2 k1 T)] + 1)^2 - ((Exp[(z e1 \[Psi]H/1000)/(2 k1 T)] - 1) Exp[Sqrt[(2 \[Rho]0*(10^3) NA (e1^2) (z^2))/(\[Epsilon]R k1 T)] (a1/2 - x)])^2)), x >= a1/2}}](*C/m^2*);
```

You can sample the `NL\[Sigma]MKS` function with

```
samples = Table[{#, NL\[Sigma]MKS[0.001, \[Psi]H, a # 10^-10]} & /@ 
    Range[1, 80, 2], {\[Psi]H, VOLTAGES}];
```

or

```
samples = Table[Table[{x, NL\[Sigma]MKS[0.001, \[Psi]H, a x 10^-10]}, {x, 1, 
     80, 2}], {\[Psi]H, VOLTAGES}];
```

Then make the plots and combine with `Show`.

```
p1 = Show[{ListPlot[samples, PlotRange -> {-2.5 10^-4, 0.01}, 
     PlotLegends -> 
      Placed[{"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Psi]\), \(H\)]\)=10 [mV]", 
        "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Psi]\), \(H\)]\)=20 [mV]", 
        "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Psi]\), \(H\)]\)=50 [mV]", 
        "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Psi]\), \(H\)]\)=100 [mV]", 
        "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Psi]\), \(H\)]\)=300 [mV]", 
        "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Psi]\), \(H\)]\)=400 [mV]"}, {0.85, 
        0.5}]], Graphics[
     Text[Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Rho]\), \(0\)]\)= 0.001 M", 
       Black, Italic, 15], {40, 8.975 10^-3}]]}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"x/a", 
     "\[Sigma](x)   [C/\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(m\), \(2\)]\)]"}, 
   ImageSize -> Large];
p2 = Plot[
   Evaluate@
    Table[L\[Sigma]MKS[0.001, \[Psi]H, a x], {\[Psi]H, VOLTAGES}], {x,
     0, 80}, PlotRange -> {-2.5 10^-4, 0.01}];

Show[p1, p2]
```

[image]